# Using hard-coded host name in logon trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger, authentication, dataguard

I need to write a trigger which prevents certain users from logging into the production database.

We use Active Data Guard.

If I hardcode the Linux hostname in the trigger to verify the host is production, then in case of "Role Change", the trigger may not work.

Correct?

---

This is a three-tier system. The end users communicate via an application server, which will use a generic name.

Here is a solution I had been contemplating implementing:

1. Have a table which will check for combination of user + server + database hostname (name of machine where database is hosted).
2. Have a `DB_ROLE_CHANGE` trigger which will get activated if the production now runs from standby
3. The `DB_ROLE_TRIGGER` will modify the table so that the database hostname now reflects new production server hostname
4. The APPSERVER and APPUSER will match OK. But since the hostname is now production - it will disallow login.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want users to connect to the standby then check the `db_role` value from `v$database`.  The primary will be `PRIMARY` and the standby wont (it'll be `PHYSICAL STANDBY` or similar).

Add a check into your trigger to bump them.

```
...
SELECT database_role INTO db_role FROM v$database;
IF db_role = 'PRIMARY' THEN (deny those users a connection)
..
```

Comment: So in that case using a USERNAME and PROFILE based approach will not work. All username and profiles will get replicated to standby and we will not be able to allow users to log into standby. Correct ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking - I thought this question was about an after logon on database trigger to prevent users on the primary DG node.  This doesn't involve profiles.

Comment: the PROFILE based solution was an alternative. Somebody in my team suggested having different username and PROFILES at production and standby sites. And these PROFILE control login behavior. But my thinking (which you seem to support) is these usernames and PROFILE will get replicated. To summarize - the PROFILE based approach will not work.